# Adding an animated svg on an input depending on the CheckValidation result

Tags: css, reactjs, node.js, svg, css-animations

I'm trying when the email input passes validation to add a tick (a css animated svg) inside the input and set the input border to green and when it doesn't pass validation to put a cross (a css animated svg) and the border to red. I am not able to fix it. For now I put that when it doesn't pass validation I add a message below the input.

The form code is the following

```
"use client";

import React, {useState } from "react";
import { FaPaperPlane } from 'react-icons/fa';
import '../app/globals.css';

function Home() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("")


    function handleChange(e) {
        setEmail(e.target.value)
    }

    const checkValidation = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const rgExp = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/g;
        if (rgExp.test(email)) {
            setMessage("Email Is Valid")
        } else if (email === "") {
            setMessage("Please, Enter your Email")
        } else if (!rgExp.test(email)) {
            setMessage("Email is not Valid")

        } else {
            setMessage("")
        }
    }

    return (
        <div id='Contact' className="relative flex items-center justify-center text-center h-[100vh]">
            <div className="mx-auto w-full text-center flex items-center justify-center text-center">
                <div className="w-full md:w-[50%] flex items-center justify-center">
                    <form action="#" className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-5 w-[80%]" onSubmit={checkValidation}>
                        <div className=''>
                            <label htmlFor="email" className="text-gray-900">
                                Full Name
                            </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                id="name"
                                className="shadow-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                                placeholder="Your Name"
                                required
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className=''>
                            <label htmlFor="email" className="text-gray-900">
                                Email Address
                            </label>
                            <label className="icon-email">
                                <input
                                    value={email}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    type="email"
                                    id="email"
                                    className="shadow-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                                    placeholder="example@domain.com"
                                />
                            </label>
                            <p className="font-bold text-[10px]">{message}</p>
                        </div >
                        <div className=''>
                            <label htmlFor="message" className="text-gray-900">
                                Your message
                            </label>
                            <textarea
                                id="message"
                                rows="5"
                                className="shadow-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                                placeholder="Type your message"
                            ></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="flex justify-center items-center gap-2 text-white bg-black px-4 py-5 rounded-lg"
                        >
                            <FaPaperPlane /> Send
                        </button>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

The check code is the following...
I only have the check code, I will do the cross code later.

HTML

```
 <svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52"> <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/> <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
* {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


.icon-email {
    background-image: url(../../public/check.svg);
}


* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #eee
}

.checkmark__circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 166;
    stroke-dashoffset: 166;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke: #7ac142;
    fill: none;
    animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards
}

.checkmark {
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    margin: 10% auto;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
    animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both
}

.checkmark__check {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    stroke-dasharray: 48;
    stroke-dashoffset: 48;
    animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards
}

@keyframes stroke {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0
    }
}

@keyframes scale {

    0%,
    100% {
        transform: none
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1)
    }
}

@keyframes fill {
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to put an svg that depends on a css (controls the animation) inside an input and even less if it depends on a validation. If there is a simpler way (a gif) will be welcome.

Thank you very much if you can help me.